# Dialogflow and Slack integration not working following the official Dialogflow documentation

Tags: api, nlp, dialogflow-es, integration, slack

DialogFlow used to be fine with Slack integration, the icon "Slack" in integration menu is the same. But got the same error:
[image: DialogFlow test Button]  [image: Error after clicking test button]

I tried with other coworkers trying to fix or at least understand the error message. The error message says that I can contact slack team for more information. The slack team answered me that DialogFlow is not their problem. So I should contact either Google Team and wait for an answer.

This slack integration with Google stopped for a reason ? Is DialogFlow <-> Slack Integration always available ?

I followed official documentation, unofficial documentation, Youtube tutorial adding every details like Keys, URl, and other scope parameters few times with that agent and other one but got same result, this error message.

I launched an old DialogFlow bot on a slack that work fine, the problem seems to be adding a new DialogFlow bot for dev in Slack. The new connection / adding the Dialog Flow Bot seems to have an issue without any other detail for now.

Hope someone got same issues and a solution or an explanation about this Dialogflow <-> Slack.

Thanks,

Cedric Vasseur

Integration between DialogFlow <--> Slack

Comment: Hi @BeepMaster, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).